# Why does indexing a Vec return a value instead of a reference as promised by the Index?

Tags: rust, operators

The documentation for the `Index` trait says that the `.index()` method returns a reference to the `Output` associated type ([link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Index.html)):

```rust
fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output;
```

For `Vec<T>` and the `usize` index, `Output` is `T`. So, I expect the variable `a` in the following snippet to have the type `&i32`.

```rust
let v = vec![0];
let a = v[0];
```

However, the type of `a` is `i32`. Why? I am learning Rust and, as far as I understand, Rust requires you to be explicit everywhere and never performs `value<->reference` conversions implicitly. Hence the question.

Comment: Coincidentally, its *because* of the design decision that "references are explicit" that the index syntax automatically dereferences because it forces you to add a `&` if you simply want to reference the element (e.g. `&v[0]`).

Comment: That's also consistent with C where `x[y]` *is* an explicit dereference, defined as `*(x+y)`, so it makes sense Rust would choose its syntax to work the way a lot of people would expect.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's an automatic dereference added when the brackets are de-sugared. The [`std::ops::Index` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Index.html) says, "`container[index]` is actually syntactic sugar for `*container.index(index)`."